# How to tell when user clicks Close in APNs message alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

According to Apple documentation, when the user clicks the View button in an alert view from an APNs message, your app is launched. However, it doesn't specify what happens when the user clicks Close, so I'm assuming nothing happens. However, I was wondering if there's a delegate method or anything that gets called to let your app know the user just clicked Close on the APNs alert. Or maybe there's a method that gets called when the user brings your app back up to let you know they clicked close while your app was in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing that the user dismissed the notification.